# Zed specification: Promotion and applying an operation more than one schema

Tags: specifications, formal-languages, formal-methods, z-notation

[image: specification]

I have an `Array` schema that keeps track of sequence of `Data` schemas. Using promotion, I am able to promote `Increment` operation to use with `Array`.

`ArrayIncrement` only increments one data inside `Array`. How do I make it such that it increments **every** `Data` in `\ran data`?

Answer (score 1):

The basic obstacle in your approach to increment all values is that the use of the relational override in Promote (last line) specifies that all values in `data'` map to the same value as in `data` except at position `index?`.

One approach is to explicitly "iterate" over the relation for all elements:

```
--- ArrayIncrement ---
| ΔArray
---
| dom data = dom data' 
| ∀ i:dom data; ΔData ·
|       θData = data i ∧ θData' = data' i ∧ Increment
------
```

In the first line of the body we state that the domain stays the same, without it there would be infinite solutions with additional elements.

In the next line we set up the variables to represent the before and after state at the specific index analogously to the second line in `Promote` of your solution.